# Are HSIC USB hubs upstream recognized in windows device manager or they need additional drivers/software?

Tags: usb, usb-hub, hsic

I try to utilize a HSIC USB hub ([USB3503](https://gr.mouser.com/datasheet/2/268/MCHP_S_A0010037308_1-2521151.pdf) USB hub), but it is not recognized on windows when I connect it to the PC's USB port.

And I start to wonder, if its HSIC upstream can be recognized by windows when connected to USB port, or windows need special software (libUSB libraries + some code to be recognized) or special libraries for HSIC devices.

As I have done a [previous question regarding the hookup of my USB3503 USB hub](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/627508/usb3503-power-supply-hookup), this question is not about my schematic/connections/layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HSIC uses different physical signalling and is not physically compatible with USB. HSIC defines its pins as "DATA" and "STROBE" (which you have on your schematic), different from the USB "DP" and "DM" differential signalling pins.

You'll need an HSIC hub with a regular USB upstream port to go between the PC and the USB3503.

Comment: All right, that is something I have not seen written anywhere, but I kind of understand it on my own at the end after hours of debugging.  Thank you for the confirmation!